# Get rid of annoying Proxy acceptance popup windows

Tags: wifi, macos, security, proxy

I have just started to use proxy. It is set up system wide (Wifi - Advanced - Proxy). But macOS keeps me asking to allow using proxies by different apps.

Like that 
[image]

It is really annoying, because I have a lot of applications installed. Furthermore it seems that some apps are requesting permissions again and again.

Please suggest, how suppress this window and allow all by default.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  According to [ask], please edit your question to include what research, steps you've already taken to resolve this issue yourself, and why those steps didn't work for you.  This prevents needless back-and-forth questions regarding "did you try this..?", "did you try that...?" as well as preventing Answers that you've already tried.

Comment: @fsb thanks for the answer, I have no idea what to try other that manually allow access